# C# Remove duplicate times within range and mark them

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates

So ive come across a slight issue with Lists in C#

I have a List that has some very similar dates. Now what i need to do is remove duplicates but where a duplicate is if its within one minute of another time, so not exactly the same.
As well as this, if there were duplicates of a specific time the object should have a flag saying so in the final list.

Now i can see how this could be done with lots of for loop, but i was hoping theres a nice way with LINQ to make this simple. So far my attempts havent been going very well though.

As an example a list of the following dates:

21/12/12 12:13:00

21/12/12 12:13:20

13/12/12 10:13:00

21/10/15 07:13:00

should turn into the list of DateDuplicate objects:

{date = 21/12/12 12:13:00, isDuplcicate=true}

{date = 13/12/12 10:13:00, isDuplcicate=false}

{date = 21/10/15 07:13:00, isDuplcicate=false}

```
public class DateDuplicate{
    public DateTime date;
    public bool isDuplicate = false;
}

List<DateDuplicate> RemoveAndMark(List<DateTime> dates){
///something nice here hopefully
}
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: I think this is too complex for one linq query. I'd tackle this by making a new list for storing your uniques, going through your original list in one single loop, and on each iteration, round the date you get to the nearest minute, then use list.Contains() to check if the uniques list already contains it, and if not, add it. The final filled uniques list is then your new filtered list.

Comment: If you really need to keep track of the duplicates, you could either fill a second list with those DateDuplicate objects while you're at it (after the `list.Contains()` check you know whether it's a duplicate) or just keep a dictionary with an occurrences count per DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 List<DateDuplicate> RemoveAndMark(List<DateTime> dates)
    {
        var dateValues =  dates.GroupBy(y => new { AddHours = y.Date.Date.AddHours(y.Hour), y.Minute}).Select(x =>

         new DateDuplicate {isDuplicate = x.Count() > 1, date = x.Key.AddHours.AddMinutes(x.Key.Minute)}

     );
        return dateValues;
    }
```

Comment: Exactly like I was attacking it except you missed the hours in your group by and select.  This would have 2015-02-02 10:05 and 2015-02-02 11:05 as duplicates.  And im guessing at that but think the input data was just incomplete.

Comment: If you add the hours you in your group by you may as well add the min as well and have `new { AddHours = y.Date.Date.AddHours(y.Hour).AddMinutes(y.Minute)}` instead of adding minutes at the end.  However your newest edit does address the key isue

Comment: @WindRaven let him/her to think about the code refactoring,LOL.thanks  again(good piont)

Comment: ah one issue with this is the following code:
`code` var def = new DateTime (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

   List<DateTime> dateList = new List<DateTime>{def,def.AddMilliseconds(1),def.AddMilliseconds(-1)}; `code`

should return 1 result when passed into the function but instead returns 2 as everything is just rounded down. Any ideas?

Comment: @RadicalSpin dateList has three values [0] = {1/1/0001 1:00:00 AM},[1] = {1/1/0001 1:00:00 AM},[2] = {1/1/0001 12:59:59 AM},the code works fine, but the problem is from your list

Comment: @Arashjo hi there, yes the code does run fine, but i get it returning 2 values despite the times being within a minute of each other, which i need not to happen
is there a way to check overall distances of time rather than just rounding down?

Comment: @Radical Spin honslty ,I don't get what are you saying:).do some search